# gerrit triggerOnEvents entire list for groovy script

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, gerrit-trigger

Team,

where can i find the entire list of this function `triggerOnEvents`? I want to know what all exists and use them as i need. like i knew two that i specified but I want to know what the all that exists in that list.

ref https://plugins.jenkins.io/gerrit-trigger/

```
    triggers {
        gerrit (
            serverName: 'git.compa.com',
            gerritProjects: [[
                compareType: 'PLAIN',
                disableStrictForbiddenFileVerification: false,
                pattern: 'team',
            ]],
            triggerOnEvents: [
                changeMerged(),
                patchsetCreated(excludeDrafts: false),
            ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general when you want to find the DSL usage of a specific plugin you can use the Jenkins Job DSL API which is actually available on your own Jenkins installation once you install the [Job DSL Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-dsl/).

To access this API go to **<YOUR_JENKINS_URL>/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.html**

IN your case, while in the API index just search for `gerrit` or `triggerOnEvents` (assuming gerrit-trigger plugin is installed) and you will get all the usage instructions.
Example from the API for triggerOnEvents:

```
triggerOnEvents {
    changeAbandoned()
    changeMerged()
    changeRestored()
    commentAdded {
        verdictCategory(String value)
        commentAddedTriggerApprovalValue(String value)
    }
    commentAddedContains {
        commentAddedCommentContains(String value)
    }
    draftPublished()
    patchsetCreated {
        commitMessageContainsRegEx(String value)
        excludeDrafts(boolean value)
        excludeNoCodeChange(boolean value)
        excludePrivateState(boolean value)
        excludeTrivialRebase(boolean value)
        excludeWipState(boolean value)
        uploaderNameContainsRegEx(String value)
    }
    privateStateChanged()
    refUpdated()
    rerunCheck()
    topicChanged()
    wipStateChanged()
}
```